# How do show an embedded conditional if es6 variable object is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a variable that will check if an object is empty...

```
const objEmpty = _.isEmpty(objStudent); // returns false because its not empty
```

How can I show that with embedding an expression is jsx code?

This is what I have : `{if empty == false ? <p>Empty<p> : <p>not empty</p>}`

How can I check something like this...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
(<div>{ empty === false ? <p>Empty</p> : <p>Not Empty</p> })
```

or, since the only difference is the 'not' word, you could just change the text based on the if

```
(<p>{ (empty === false ? '' : 'Not') + ' Empty' }</p>)
```

You should be aware that when you use the curly braces in JSX, it will automatically create a span tag that wraps around that.

I noticed in the example you posted, that the "Empty" paragraph was missing a closing tag.  You had `<p>Empty<p>` when it should have been `<p>Empty</p>`

Comment: Hmm seems to throw Empty no matter what. I think that might be on my side tho. Thank you !

Comment: If i wanted to check for 2 values being false, how would I do that? ie: `      <div>{isEmptyStudents && isEmptyTeachers === false ? <span>Persons found!</span> : <p>No persons found</p>}</div>`
`

Comment: <div>{ isEmptyStudents === false && isEmptyTeachers === false ? <span>Persons found!</span> : <p>No persons found</p>}</div>